# Multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql-server, records, multiple-records

UPDATE
 first i try this sp with filter id

```
select Row_number()
 OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'RowNumber',
 vf.* 
 from login ld,
 veh vf  where
(ld.fid=vf.fid) 
and ld.id = '0257'
and ld.id <> 'NA' 
and vf.CustID <> 'None'  
and vf.Simo <> 'None'  
Order by Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
```

and this show result like this

```
RowNumber   FID     Oid     CustID      DID     Simo    RNo
1          166  MT255   M2522      1368     LM00    LE270
```

now when i remove filter ld.id and try this

```
select Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  AS 'RowNumber',
 vf.* 
 from login ld,
 veh vf  where
(ld.fid = cast(vf.fid as varchar(max)))
and ld.id <> 'NA' 
and vf.CustID <> 'None' 
and vf.SimNo <> 'None'  
Order by Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
```

then this show mutlple result

```
RowNumber   FID     Oid     CustID      DID     Simo    RNo
1          166    MT255   M2522      1368     LM00    LE270
2          166    MT255   M2522      1368     LM00    LE270
3          166    MT255   M2522      1368     LM00    LE270
```

and when i remove this

```
(ld.fid = cast(vf.fid as varchar(max)))
```

and write this

```
(ld.fid=vf.fid)
```

then this show error
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

**update**

when i `select * from Login where iD='0257'`
then

```
ID    FID   
0257    166
```

and when i try
`select * from Login where FID='166'` then

```
ID          FID 
0257        166 
022         166 
0258        166
```

and `select * from Vehicle where FID='166'`

```
FID     Oid     CustID      DID     Simo    RNo
 166  MT255   M2522      1368     LM00    LE270
```

Comment: Why does the field you join on have different types?

Comment: your rownumber makes the distinct useless. Distinct will leave out any duplicate record, but your rownumber makes that you have no duplicate records

Comment: but when i check there is only record in table @GuidoG

Comment: i think there is issue in this part .. (ld.fid = cast(vf.fid as varchar(max))) if we want to convert ld.fid in int so how i do that ..

Comment: yes but you have joined table login with table veh so for every record in login your query will get all records in veh

Comment: ok how i convert this ld.fid in int

Comment: Why dont you show us some data in both tables and an example of what you want your result to look like. Then we will be much better able to help you

Comment: @GuidoG check update i provide data

Comment: What is the data in both tables when doing select * from login and select * from veh ? And then what is the result you want to have ? That is what we need to know

Comment: The question changed from why are there duplicates to conversion error ?

Comment: @GuidoG check update

Comment: @GuidoG any solution

Comment: in table login you have a record with ID= 0257 and FID= 16196 but als a record with ID=0257 and FID= 166 ??

Comment: @GuidoG sorry typing error this is 166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix the conversion error you can try this
(Assuming login.fid is a varchar field and veh is not a varchar field)

```
SELECT  distinct 
        vf.RegNo
FROM login ld
  inner join veh vf on ld.fid = convert(varchar, isnull(vf.fid,''))
where ld.id  <> 'NA'
AND vf.CustID  <> 'None'
AND vf.Simo  <> 'None'
```

**EDIT: ok what if login.fid is varhcar and vhe,fid is int then how to convert login.fid to int?**

```
SELECT  distinct 
        vf.RegNo
FROM login ld
  inner join veh vf on convert(int, isnull(ld.fid, 0)) = vf.fid
where ld.id  <> 'NA'
AND vf.CustID  <> 'None'
AND vf.Simo  <> 'None'
```

This will go wrong if there is any value in login.fid that is not convertable to int

**EDIT:
you can try to fix that like this but there is no guarantie it will always work.**

```
SELECT  distinct 
        vf.RegNo
FROM login ld
  inner join veh vf on case when isnumeric(ld.fid) = 1 then convert(int, isnull(ld.fid, 0)) else -1 end = vf.fid
where ld.id  <> 'NA'
AND vf.CustID  <> 'None'
AND vf.Simo  <> 'None'
```

Comment: this answer is intented to fix the conversion error. It is not clear to me anymore what your question is you change if from conversion error to multiple records and back.

Comment: ok what if login.fid is varhcar and vhe,fid is int then how to convert login.fid to int?

Comment: your edit show error .. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

Comment: what are the datatypes for fid in both tables ? If there is a varchar field make sure there are no empty strings in it (fid = ''). If the latter is the case than there is an error in your inserting/updating software, empty string should be forbidden and modified to null

Comment: are there any records in login with an empty string in the field fid ?

Comment: or a value that is not convertable to int ?

Comment: see my updated answer, it will try to work around non convertable values in login.fid

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'. error

Comment: try it again I updated it, but how about my question about empty strings in the field fid ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using distinct when you are using `ROW_NUMBER()` because it will generate a different value for each row and make the combination of 'RowNumber' and 'RegNo' unique. Use the below query instead to get required results.

```
Select Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RowNumber',*
   from
   (

    SELECT  distinct 
        vf.RegNo
    FROM login ld
        ,veh vf
    WHERE (ld.fid = cast(vf.fid as varchar(max)))
        AND ld.id  <> 'NA'
        AND vf.CustID  <> 'None'
        AND vf.Simo  <> 'None'

 ) tab
 ORDER BY RowNumber,
 vf.RegNo
```

Comment: I would use the left/inner join syntax in stead of this obsolete joining syntax

Comment: this show error The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: moved order by outside sub query. This will resolve the error